# How do use MyWebpart in EventReceiver?

Tags: 2010, web-part, visual-studio

I created a webpart with many properties.

I want add it in EventReceiver and set properties.

How do use MyWebpart in EventReceiver?

Comment: You cannot use one webpart within another webpart. You can create a webpart connectivity which will transfer values from one webpart to another.

Comment: I want add a webpart to special page in special eventreciver. There is no solution؟!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [SPLimitedWebPartManager](http://SPLimitedWebPartManager) and it's [AddWebPart](http://webPartManager.AddWebPart%28webPart,%20zoneID,%20zoneIndex%29) method for this purpose.

To create the SPLimitedWebPartManager object targeted to a specific page, use [SPWeb.GetLimitedWebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlimitedwebpartmanager.aspx) method.

Code example:

```
var webpart = new MyWebPart();
webpart.Title = "This is my webpart!";
webpart.MyCustomProperty = "Hello";
using (var manager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("/site-relative/path/to/page.aspx"))
{
    manager.AddWebPart(webpart, "Main", 1);
}
```

Actually, this is a common way to add a webpart to a page in SharePoint. And I don't see why it would not work from within an event receiver.

P.S. Also I suspect, that depending from the kind (sync/async) of the event receiver, you may have to run this code with elevated privilegies.

Comment: Thanks, I have a wsp file , that active feature in server . when how do new MyWebPart in solution ?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Do you mean you have two separate wsps? In this case, you can add a reference to the assembly which stores `MyWebPart` class to your solution, and then, the corresponding `using` statement to the event receiver - this way you can use class identifier in your code.

Comment: yes, It is possible؟؟ . another quastion : if i use this code for add webpart , how do open edit webpart in page ?

Comment: This is another question. I would recommend you to post it separately. Though, a quick Google search led me to the following post, which describes how you can open a webpart tool pane, if you know the webpart's ID (you can grab it easily from the *SPLimitedWebPartManager* object): http://spdeveloper.net/2011/07/create-open-tool-pane-link-in-custom-net-web-parts-for-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answer below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419632/possible-to-load-a-web-part-inside-another

I will reproduce the answer here (for convenience), It is not my code, I checked it and it should be OK.

```
public class WebPartWrapper : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart {
    protected override void CreateChildControls() {    
        Panel pnl = new Panel();
        this.Controls.Add(pnl);
        var factory = new WebPartFactory()
        WebPart dynamicPart = factory.CreateWebPart("RSSViewer", this.Guid);
        pnl.Controls.Add(dynamicPart);
    }
}

public class WebPartFactory {
    public WebPart CreateWebpart(string webpartName, Guid parentWebPartGuid)
    {
        var config = ConfigurationFactory.LoadConfiguration(webpartName);

        Assembly webPartAssembly = Assembly.Load(config.Assembly);
        Type webPartType = webPartAssembly.GetType(config.Class);
        object actualWebPart = Activator.CreateInstance(webPartType);

        foreach (var item in config.Properties)
        {
            PropertyInfo webPartProperty = webPartType.GetProperty(item.Name);
            object webPartPropertyValue = Convert.ChangeType(itemValue, Type.GetType(item.Type));
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value))
                webPartProperty.SetValue(actualWebPart, webPartPropertyValue, null);
        }

        RunMethod("set_StorageKeyInternal", actualWebPart, new object[] { parentWebPartGuid });
        return actualWebPart as WebPart;
    }

    private void RunMethod(string methodName, object objectInstance, object[] methodParameters)
    {
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.NonPublic;

        Type t = objectInstance.GetType();
        MethodInfo m = GetMethod(t, methodName, flags);
        if (m != null)
        {
            m.Invoke(objectInstance, methodParameters);
        }
    }

    private MethodInfo GetMethod(Type instanceType, string methodName, BindingFlags flags)
    {
        MethodInfo m = instanceType.GetMethod(methodName, flags);
        if (m != null)
        {
            return m;
        }

        if (instanceType.GetType() == typeof(object) || instanceType.BaseType == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return GetMethod(instanceType.BaseType, methodName, flags);
    } 
}
```

This code needs some explaining... Please excuse me if it does not compile, I had to remove a fair bit of the original code, it was very implementation specific stuff. I've not shown the "config" class either, it's just a container for configuration of webparts, just a bunch of properties. There are 2 issues I'd like to discuss in more detail:

1. parentWebPartGuid - This is the Guid (UniqueId?) of the hosting
   webpart. For some reason we have to set "StorageKeyInternal" to this
   value, using reflection (it's a private property). You can possibly
   get away with not setting it, but at least for the majority of
   webparts we had to set it.
2. config.Properties - This is the config values (we set them in a
       custom .xml file, but feel free to get this from anywhere). It can
       look a little like this..

In our framework we also support stuff like dynamic property values etc., but that's for another day... Hope this all makes sense and can help somebody.

Comment: Thanks , but i don't understand your code. what is (ConfigurationFactory)?

Comment: It's explained. It's not my code but I manage to understand it. It's a place to store some values for eacht webpart. U can change this to a xmlfile, database, SPList, or a generic collection... This code is loaded a webpart based on its name, because we need to know its asembly and classname we are storing those values in "ConfigFactory" for easy accessing